# Adding Migrator.NET to an existing production database

Tags: c#, database, migration, migratordotnet

I am interested in starting to use Migrator.NET with an existing production database.  I have a some initial states that I need to support:

a) Database is at current release  (release where we started using Migrator), no upgrade necessary.  Initialize Migrator to prepare for future database upgrades.

b) No database present, run my initial database create script (to get our database up to the point started using Migrator). Initialize Migrator version as 0 (or 1?) to prepare for future database upgrades.  Run any database migrations that may be required after the starting  point is initialized.

Any thoughts on how this is best handled?

btw, I am open to other solutions besides Migrator .NET.  This seems to be the most mature, even though it hasn't been developed in over a year.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) and [RoundhousE](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse) instead. I used to use Migrator.NET but it got abandoned unfortuntately.

Your requirements look to be fairly standard. I think both of them support this scenario. You can either start with a baseline sql script to create the database schema or say that the current database is the starting point and save a copy of the database (schema and data) then restore that database to initialize the process.